# Appending element-wise a `Series` to an existing `Series` of lists

Tags: python, pandas

Say that I have a series of list objects, and another series of values, e.g.,

```py
a = pd.Series([
    [1],
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5],
    [],
    [2],
    [3, 6],
])

b = pd.Series([10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60])
```

I wish to append `b` element-wise to `a`, i.e., to get

```py
result = pd.Series([
    [1, 10],
    [1, 2, 3, 20],
    [4, 5, 30],
    [40],
    [2, 50],
    [3, 6, 60],
])
```

What is the best way to go about this?

Note, if it would make things easier to have a `pd.Series` of `pd.array` objects (or something else) instead of `list` objects, that's fine.

As a side point, is there any easy way to remove NaN values from the individual lists in a series like `a` or `result`?

Comment: Usually you want to avoid storing complex objects in a DataFrame or Series, as you'll lose a lot of the efficiency and performance of pandas when you attempt to do almost any kind of operation. You can typically get a similar organization using a MultiIndex, which then makes any later operations much easier to do

Comment: @ALollz Ah, how would I go about that? Feel free to leave an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use `zip`, which will in general be faster than `apply`:

```
pd.Series([lst + [e] for lst, e in zip(a, b)])

0          [1, 10]
1    [1, 2, 3, 20]
2       [4, 5, 30]
3             [40]
4          [2, 50]
5       [3, 6, 60]
dtype: object
```

To modify `a` inplace:

```
for lst, e in zip(a, b): lst.append(e)

a
0          [1, 10]
1    [1, 2, 3, 20]
2       [4, 5, 30]
3             [40]
4          [2, 50]
5       [3, 6, 60]
dtype: object
```

Benchmark against `apply`:

```
timeit("a + b.apply(lambda x : [x])", number=100, globals=globals())
0.11637999999948079

timeit("pd.Series([lst + [e] for lst, e in zip(a, b)])", number=100, globals=globals())
0.04336999999941327
```

---

To remove `null` values:

```
a = pd.Series([
    [1],
    [1, 2, 3, np.nan],
    [4, 5],
    [],
    [2],
    [3, np.nan, 6],
])

a
0               [1]
1    [1, 2, 3, nan]
2            [4, 5]
3                []
4               [2]
5       [3, nan, 6]
dtype: object

a.apply(lambda lst: [x for x in lst if pd.notnull(x)])

0          [1]
1    [1, 2, 3]
2       [4, 5]
3           []
4          [2]
5       [3, 6]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you, that's good to know about `zip` too.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html#pandas.Series.apply) to convert each element to a list and then concat:

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.Series([
    [1],
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5],
    [],
    [2],
    [3, 6],
])

b = pd.Series([10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60])


res = a + b.apply(lambda x : [x])
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
0          [1, 10]
1    [1, 2, 3, 20]
2       [4, 5, 30]
3             [40]
4          [2, 50]
5       [3, 6, 60]
dtype: object
```

Alternative:

```
res = a + pd.Series(b.to_frame().to_numpy().tolist())
```

Comment: Thanks very much.